# Fuelux Datagrid breaks bootstrap dropdown menus

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, datagrid, fuelux

I am having troubles with FuelUX's datagrid component. One the page of my site where I implement the datagrid component, the dropdown menus provided by bootstrap stop working.

I'm using:jQuery 1.9.0, fuelUX 2.3.0, Bootstrap 2.3.1
I am NOT using: requireJS.

I am bringing in the FuelUX css files and the loader.js file. The bootstrap menus work on every other page except for this one. The datagrid component seems to operate just fine except that it's own select menus aren't working either.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By using the loader.js from Fuel UX you are already bringing in Bootstrap. Fuel UX 2.3.0 includes Bootstrap 2.3.0 so if your page is additionally loading Bootstrap 2.3.1 it could be a conflict. Please see this example http://tinkerbin.com/0RXOjPNd which loads jQuery 1.9.1 and Fuel UX/Bootstrap 2.3.0. Note that you do need to click the green RUN button to start the script on tinkerbin.

The Fuel UX bugfix release 2.3.1 - which will also include Bootstrap 2.3.1 - will be released soon but if you want to try the near-complete work in progress the distribution files are in the master branch at https://github.com/ExactTarget/fuelux/tree/master/dist

I hope this gets you running!

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense and worked perfectly. I removed my standalone Bootstrap version for that one page and relied on the version that FuelUX provides. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue and had it fixed by removing my bootstrap inclusion.  Only problem tough : I need an earlier bootstrap than the one loaded in fuelux (I need v3, fuelux loads v2).  Any idea how to solve that?

Answer (score 0):

I faced with the same issue:

"javascripts/libs/bootstrap.js"

"javascripts/libs/loader.min.js"

the rows above are in conflict states: all my bootstrap dropdowns are broken after including loader.min.js.
The first workaround I found was to separate these two js files on the page where I use Fuel UX wizard. But as it was turned out then my bootstrap accordion became broken, cause this page in total use bootstrap.js.

I resolved this issue with updating  Fuel UX wizard.js which I needed with removing AMD related code. And this works.

I use bootstrap v3.1.1 and the last Fuel UX - v2.6.0 - 2014-02-14
Waiting for correct fix from Fuel UX creators.